# devise and current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, declarative-authorization

I have a Rails 3 app that I am trying to implement devise and declarative_authorization.
An important part of declarative_authorization is the presence of a function "role_symbols" within the user model.
Because of the way I implement roles, I am implementing an instance method within the User model to keep track of a value (let's call foo) as such:

```
  attr_accessor :foo

  def foo=(val)
    @foo = val
  end

  def foo
    @foo
  end
```

Then we will use the value of foo inside the role_symbols method to limit the valid roles, maybe like this:

```
def role_symbols
  roles.where("foo = ?", @foo).name.underscore.to_sym
end
```

The issue is when I try to set the value of foo for the current_user in a controller, the value doesn't stick, for example:

```
current_user.foo = 99
```

is successful, but when I check the value in another view (or controller), the value of current_user.foo is nil.

Isn't the current_user object just a User object that is persisted in the Session?
If so, is there some lock on setting instance values within the current_user object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was lucky enough to find the answer here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20140113211231/http://blog.drivingthevortex.nl/2010/01/24/using-declarative_authorization-with-subdomains/